# Aligning text to right side of table view cell whose height and width are dynamically set

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a table view whose height is dynamically set and max-width is 100 less than the screen width. These cells are aligned to the left or right side to create chat bubbles. I want to align parts of the text to the right end for the cell aligned to the right. But setting `NSMutableParagraphStyle` to `.right` for the text's attributed string property produces unexpected results.

My cell code:

```
class DiscussionChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {
        
    private let messageLabel: UILabel
    private let senderNameLabel: UILabel
    private let messageBubble: UIView
    
    private var bubbleLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var bubbleTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        
        messageLabel = UILabel()
        senderNameLabel = UILabel()
        messageBubble = UIView()
        
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
                
        self.contentView.addSubview(messageBubble)
        messageBubble.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        messageBubble.addSubview(senderNameLabel)
        senderNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        senderNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        senderNameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        senderNameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        senderNameLabel.textColor = .white
        
        messageBubble.addSubview(messageLabel)
        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        messageLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        messageLabel.textColor = .white
        
        // set hugging and compression resistance for Name label
        senderNameLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        senderNameLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        
        // create bubble Leading and Trailing constraints
        bubbleLeadingConstraint = messageBubble.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10)
        bubbleTrailingConstraint = messageBubble.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
        
        // priority will be changed in configureCell()
        bubbleLeadingConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        bubbleTrailingConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            bubbleLeadingConstraint,
            bubbleTrailingConstraint,
            
            messageBubble.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            messageBubble.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            
            messageBubble.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.contentView.widthAnchor, constant: -100),
            
            senderNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageBubble.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            senderNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageBubble.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            senderNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageBubble.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            
            messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: senderNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageBubble.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageBubble.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageBubble.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            
        ])
        
        // corners will have radius: 10
        messageBubble.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configureCell(message: DiscussionMessage, isSender: Bool) {
        senderNameLabel.text = message.userName + " " + message.userCountryEmoji
        
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: message.messageTimestamp)

        let dayTimePeriodFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dayTimePeriodFormatter.timeZone = .current
        
        dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        let dateString = dayTimePeriodFormatter.string(from: date)
        
        let messageFont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 13)!
        let sentTimeFont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic", size: 11)!

        let messageTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: messageFont]
        
        let setTimeTextParagraphStyle =  NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        setTimeTextParagraphStyle.alignment = isSender ? .right : .left

        let sentTimeTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: sentTimeFont, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: setTimeTextParagraphStyle]

        let messageString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message.message + "\n\n",
        attributes: messageTextAttributes)
        
        let sentTimeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: dateString, attributes: sentTimeTextAttributes)

        messageString.append(sentTimeString)
            
//        messageLabel.text = message.message + "\n\n" + dateString
        messageLabel.attributedText = messageString
                
        messageLabel.textColor = isSender ? .black : .white
        senderNameLabel.textColor = isSender ? .black : .white

        bubbleLeadingConstraint.priority = isSender ? .defaultLow : .defaultHigh
        bubbleTrailingConstraint.priority = isSender ? .defaultHigh : .defaultLow
        
        messageBubble.backgroundColor = isSender ? accentColor : .gray
        
        let senderCorners: CACornerMask = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
        let nonSenderCorners: CACornerMask =  [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            messageBubble.layer.maskedCorners = isSender ?
                // topLeft, topRight, bottomRight
                senderCorners
                :
                // topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft
                nonSenderCorners
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            
            let corners: CACornerMask = isSender ? senderCorners : nonSenderCorners
            
            var cornerMask = UIRectCorner()
            if(corners.contains(.layerMinXMinYCorner)){
                cornerMask.insert(.topLeft)
            }
            if(corners.contains(.layerMaxXMinYCorner)){
                cornerMask.insert(.topRight)
            }
            if(corners.contains(.layerMinXMaxYCorner)){
                cornerMask.insert(.bottomLeft)
            }
            if(corners.contains(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner)){
                cornerMask.insert(.bottomRight)
            }
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: cornerMask, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            messageBubble.layer.mask = mask
        }
        
    }
}
```

I want the time when aligned right, to just end at the right edge of the cell with the width the same as it was when left alignd. But the width of the cell grows.

With `setTimeTextParagraphStyle.alignment = isSender ? .right : .left`

[image]

With `setTimeTextParagraphStyle.alignment = isSender ? .left OR .justified : .left`

[image]

Comment: Do you want the name and message to *also* be right-aligned? Or just the "time"?

Comment: I want to align just the time

Comment: Then you are probably better off adding another `UILabel` for the time and setting its `.textAlignment`

Comment: Ah that sucks! okay I'll do that.